# How to show the first x bytes using hexdump?

Tags: linux, bash, unix

I have two files and I want to see if the first 40 bytes are similar. How can I do this using hex dump?

Comment: 'Compare first N bytes' is different than 'Show first N bytes'.  Consider this NOT A DUPLICATE.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you are using the BSD `hexdump` utility (which will also be installed as `hd`, with a different default output format) then you can supply the `-n40` command line parameter to limit the dump to the first 40 bytes:

```
hexdump -n40 filename
```

If you are using the Posix standard `od`, you need a capital `N`. You might find the following invocation useful:

```
od -N40 -w40 -tx1 -Ax filename
```

(You can do that with `hexdump`, too, but the format string is more work to figure out :) ).

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
head -c 40 myfile | hexdump
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you need hexdump here,

```
diff <(dd bs=1 count=40 if=file1) <(dd bs=1 count=40 if=file2)
```

with hexdump:

```
diff <(dd bs=1 count=40 if=file1|hexdump) <(dd bs=1 count=40 if=file2|hexdump)
```

Comment: Assuming that the files are not text files (in other words, they have various non-printing characters), then `diff` will only tell you whether the files are identical or not. Using `hd` (or `hexdump`, but `hd` is usually a friendlier format), you can tell if they are *similar*, as in the question. BTW, `dd bs=40 count=1` is more efficient, and you probably want to toss dd's byte count reports into the bitbucket (`2>>/dev/null`)

Comment: I would like to actually see them. Thanks.